# Speed-up RESTORE DATABASE

Tags: sql-server, database, database-performance, database-backups, database-restore

I'm using MS SQL 2008 R2 (10.50.1600)

I wonder why my database which is very tiny (nearly 1200 rows, only 2 tables) is restoring so slow (12-15 sec). I suppose it's involved with log file within database (I'm not sure). The thing is I don't care about the log file. I'm interesting in only with the mdf file. Is it possible to speed-up restoring database ? I'm afraid it'll take forever in case of some larger databases. Time of restoring is important for me.

I'm doing this like this :

```
BACKUP DATABASE TEST TO DISK = 'myDataBase' WITH INIT

RESTORE DATABASE TEST 
FROM DISK = 'myDataBase' 
WITH REPLACE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Processed 256 pages for database 'myDataBase', file 'myDataBase' on file 1.
Processed 1 pages for database 'myDataBase', file 'myDataBase_log' on file 1.
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 257 pages in 12.218 seconds (0.164 MB/sec).
```

I've done some other test and I created brand new database which is empty. Restoring this database took only fractions of a secound. Backup is the same as previously. Restore report :

```
Processed 176 pages for database 'TEST', file 'TEST' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'TEST', file 'TEST_log' on file 1.
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 178 pages in 0.035 seconds (39.676 MB/sec).
```

Does someone have any idea what can be done with this ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn on *Instant File Initialization*

Details: http://blog.devart.com/instant-file-initialization-killer-feature-for-sql-server.html

Comment: Thanks. It helped. I see significant speedup of restoring database operation